# Interactive search bar using Node and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Currently I've received a test for a junior position in which they want the following in Node-Express-Mongo.

First they want a search bar in which revives parameter that is send as a query to API that gives you results(MovieAPI). They want that when the specific item(movie) is found(clicked) to save it locally in mongoDB. I dont have problem with any of that, my question for you is how to make interactive search bar, and with that i mean can i receive items from API as "suggestions" to my search(when user is typing) and how to do that.

I want to receive more than 1 suggestion so when the user clicks a single item its directly saved to mongoDB and redirected to the item info.

The suggestion search bar is not the part of the task but i would like to implement it if possible.

No code here, just need ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think MongoDB's full-text search + nodejs WebSocket server.
I imagine this something like that

1. > Client ends typing in search bar
2. > Client sends a request for a suggestion
3. > Server received the request and request a full-text search on mongo
4. > Server sends response from mongo
5. > Client display received a message

But remember that MongoDB is a database, not search engine I would suggest using something like elastic search.

But if you want recommendations based on the connection between movies (e.g. same directors, actors, etc.) chose some graph databases like neo4j because Document-based NoSQL doesn't store connection well.

If your recommendation is based on the numeric value you can just search for the movies with the closest values to searched one

I would just search your local DB (it doesn't matter what type it is )for the suggestion if API cant provide those

Comment: Thank you for your response, quick question tho. The first thing that needs to happen(if i want to do this) is displaying message to a client that is going from  OMDb API(response to the search) then when the user clicks it the result of the search is saved in database. I believe your approach is correct I just wonder how it works when fetching data from somewhere else.

Comment: I don't really by what parameters are you fetching data, so my response is so generic, but if you get more than one result I think you should store all for recommendation and just add property clicked or sth like this